# Why is MAX-SAT a generalisation of the SAT problem?

Tags: sat, satisfiability

According to Wikipedia, the maximum satisfiability problem (MAX-SAT) is the problem of determining the maximum number of clauses, of a given Boolean formula in conjunctive normal form, that can be made true by an assignment of truth values to the variables of the formula. It is a generalisation of the Boolean satisfiability problem, which asks whether there exists a truth assignment that makes all clauses true.

I do not understand the 2nd sentence on how MAX-SAT is a generalisation of SAT. According to Wikipedia, SAT asks whether the variables of a given Boolean formula can be consistently replaced by the values TRUE or FALSE in such a way that the formula evaluates to TRUE.

The reason why I am asking this is because of the paper 'Semidefinite Optimization Approaches for Satisfiability and Maximum-Satisfiability Problems', where I would like to try Semidefinite optimisation techniques to solve some SAT problems I have at hand.

Comment: SAT -> *Is* the maximum number of satisfiable clauses *exactly equal to* the number of clauses? That's a yes/no question that's far more specific than MAX-SAT -> *How large is* the maximum number of satisfiable clauses. It could be equal to the number of clauses, less than it, or 0.

Comment: Another way to look at this is as follows. A MaxSAT problem is comprised by a set of hard clauses `H` and a set of soft clauses `S`. Solving a MaxSAT problem `H,S` with an empty set of soft clauses `S`, is equivalent to solving a SAT problem `H`. *(They have the exact same solutions, except for the value of the [implicit] cost-function which is always `0`).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine turning each of your clauses to implications, by adding `p -> q` where `p` is a fresh variable for each clause `q` you have in your original problem. Then, a satisfying instance to this modified problem is a solution to `MAXSAT` problem of the original, when you pick those clauses where the solver assigned `true` to the corresponding `p`. This gives you a maxsat solver, albeit a crappy one.

Now imagine you have a system that makes sure it makes as many of those `p`'s true as possible. That combination now gives you a maxsat solver, i.e., one that can optimize the number of `p`s that are true. This way you get a nice maxsat solver for your original problem, i.e., you can reduce the maxsat problem to sat, provided you have something that maximizes the number of true assignment to those `p`'s that you introduce through the translation.

@PatrickTrentin can probably explain much better! The vZ paper (the maxsat engine associated with z3) is also a very nice and simple read on this topic: https://backend.orbit.dtu.dk/ws/portalfiles/portal/110977246/Bj_rner_Phan_Fleckenstein_Unknown_Z_An_Optimizing_SMT_Solver_1.pdf

Comment: Some Context: the linked paper presents a MaxSAT engine lifted to the SMT case, that is, a MaxSMT solver. +1